# Realm Java Equivalent of ANY and ALL NSPredicate Aggregate Operators

Tags: java, android, realm

In iOS with Realm where are allowed to make query calls with NSPredicates. This is not a thing in Realm Java for Android. However most of the NSPredicate operators are present in Realm Java and allowed me to make a simple NSPredicate Parser for my Android application (Building a parser was necessary due to the complex nature of the iOS/Android App).

How can I replicate the ANY and ALL NSPredicate Aggregate Operators, used on iOS, on Android using Realm Java in a manner that would support complex queries?

Comment: ANY should be easy as that's a simple link query, but I don't think ALL is possible.

Comment: Got it. I built out support for ANY using the link queries. For All will I have to make a realm query, get the realm results, filter those manually, and then continue with the rest of my query on those results? Is that even possible. @EpicPandaForce

Comment: Do I understand `ALL` correctly that `true if ALL linked items match the given condition`? Because I don't think that is possible *across links* in Realm-Java, only on the "table" you are currently operating on. :(

Comment: That would be correct. So that puts a bit of a damper on that. Would the NSPredicate Aggregate Operator NONE be possible to build with the link queries. Ex. `NONE events.id CONTAINS someString` or `NONE events.value >= 10` @EpicPandaForce

Comment: I recommend taking this over to https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues because I think Realm-Java only supports `ANY`